# dynamic json tree creation using a database

Tags: javascript, java, json, dynamic

I recently came accross a problem which is as follows:
I need to create a json tree in java/javascript where the data of the json tree is obtained from MySql Database.
In the above I could not find the documents
So pls help me make the above.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: @Sanjay Kumar N S can you pls help me with that

Comment: I dont know much about java coding. This way of asking question is not romoting in stack overflow. You have to try something and put the code here so that others can figure out the mistakes.

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS I did make a json tree where the data set was fixed but the real problem came up when I had to make the data come dynamically and surprisingly no code or example was present to demonstrate the above. So I thought it would be better that I ask this huge knowledge resource  so that not only I but others as well are benifitted with that.. So if you have any idea on that do let me know

Comment: How will the others find the mistake ... when I don't know how to make the thing in the first place work in the desired manner

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think getting tree objects in java is defficult. i tried it. you can use another way. when click a folder, you will get inside folder files or folders. **here i used dropbox Api to do it. please get an idea from it. try your idea.**

## treeview.html:

```
<!-- Nested list template -->
              <script type="text/ng-template" id="items_renderer.html">
                <div ui-tree-handle>
                <span ng-show="item.file" class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>
                  <a ng-hide="item.file" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this);toggleMe(this)">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed}">
                  </span></a>
                  {{item.title}}
                  <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="remove(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                  <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="newSubItem(this)" style="margin-right: 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                </div>
                <ol ui-tree-nodes="options" ng-model="item.items" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
                  <li ng-repeat="item in item.items" collapsed="true" ui-tree-node ng-include="'items_renderer.html'">
                  </li>
                </ol>
              </script>

              <div ui-tree="options">
                <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="list" >
                  <li ng-repeat="item in list track by $index"  ui-tree-node collapsed="true" ng-include="'items_renderer.html'"></li>
                </ol>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

## treecontroller.js:

```
app.controller('treeController',['$scope', '$http','fileUpload', function($scope, $http,fileUpload) {

    console.log("$$$ tree controller has been initialized $$$")

    /** To get list of files from the dropbox */
    var files  = [];
    $scope.list = [];
    var foldername = '';
    /***  we call dropbox cloud when the user wants and we get files and
     *  folders for an initialization*/

    $scope.getListOfFiles = function() {
        var foldername = "/";
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/dropbox_api_.10/dropbox/getListOfFiles/?folderPath=" + foldername)
        .success(function(data, status) {
            console.log("List of files from dropbox folder &&&&", angular.toJson(data));
            $scope.list = data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('error');
        });
    }

    var folders = [];
    var buildFloderPath = function(scope) {
        if (scope.$parentNodeScope != null) {
            folders.push(scope.$parentNodeScope.$modelValue.title);
            buildFloderPath(scope.$parentNodeScope);
        }
    };

    /** When we call, we expand tree here and clear when collapse tree*/
    $scope.toggleMe = function(scope) {
        folders = [];
        foldername="";
        if (!scope.collapsed) {
            var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;
            folders.push(nodeData.title);
            buildFloderPath(scope);
            console.log(angular.toJson(folders));

            for (var i = folders.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                foldername += "/" + folders[i];
            }
            /***/
            //continueFileUploading(foldername);

            $http.get("http://localhost:8080/dropbox_api_.10/dropbox/getListOfFiles/?folderPath=" + foldername)
            .success(function(data, status) {
                console.log(" @@@@ Selected path @@@",foldername);
                console.log("List of files from dropbox folder &&&&", angular.toJson(data));
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    nodeData.items.push(data[i]);
                }
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('error');
            });
        }
        else{
            var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;
            nodeData.items = [];

        }
    };



    $scope.getListOfFiles();
    /*****************/

    $scope.remove = function(scope) {
        scope.remove();
    };

    $scope.toggle = function(scope) {
        scope.toggle();
    };

    $scope.newSubItem = function(scope) {
        var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;
        nodeData.items.push({
            id : nodeData.id * 10 + nodeData.items.length,
            title : nodeData.title + '.' + (nodeData.items.length + 1),
            items : []
    });
    };
}]);
```

## java:

```
public ArrayList<String> listDropboxFolders(@RequestParam("folderPath") String folderPath) throws DbxException {

        ArrayList<String> fileList=new ArrayList<String>();
        for (DbxEntry child : listing.children) {
            //File child;
            if(child.isFolder()){
                fileList.add(child.name);
                System.out.println("file is theere"+child.name);
            }else{
                System.out.println("file name **"+child.name);
            }
            child.toString());
        }
        return fileList;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a server-side language to connect to the MySql database and put out the data to the client.

Basic example:

PHP (getJSON.php)

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');

$strSQL = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
$result = $db->query($sql)
$rows = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $rows[] = $row;
    }
}

$db->close()
print json_encode($rows);
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://{your-host}/getJSON.php',
   dataType: 'JSON',

   success: function(data, status) {
        console.log(data)
   },
   error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.statusText + " : " + e.responseText);
   }
});
```

code is not tested but this is basicly it :)